# C++ Constructor and Getting it to Display a Default Answer

Tags: c++, constructor

So I'm still working on this problem, and thought I had it correct. However, now it only displays the "ABC Industries" and "Report", instead of only doing that if no information is entered. Where am I messing up in my code?

```
//This program displays a company's name and report.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

class Heading {
private:
    string company;
    string report;

public:
    Heading() {
        company = "ABC Industries";
        report = "Report";
    }


    Heading(string c, string r) {
        company = c;
        report = r;
    }


    void storeInfo(string company, string report);

    string getCompany() {
        return company;
    }
    string getReport() {
        return report;
    }
};


void Heading::storeInfo(string c, string r) {
    c = company;
    r = report;
}

void storeInfo(Heading&);
void showInfo(HANDLE, Heading);
void placeCursor(HANDLE, Heading);

int main() {
    Heading company;
    HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    storeInfo(company);
    showInfo(screen, company);
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

/*****storeInfo*****/
void storeInfo(Heading &item) {
    string company;
    string report;
    cout << "\nPlease enter the company name.\n";
    getline(cin, company);
    cout << "\nPlease enter the report name.\n";
    \
    getline(cin, report);
    item.storeInfo(company, report);
}

/*****placeCursor*****/
void placeCursor(HANDLE screen, int row, int col) {
    COORD position;
    position.Y = row;
    position.X = col;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);
}

/*****showInfo*****/
void showInfo(HANDLE screen, Heading item) {
    system("cls");
    placeCursor(screen, 6, 25);
    cout << "********************************" << endl;
    placeCursor(screen, 8, 32);
    cout << item.getCompany() << endl;
    placeCursor(screen, 11, 36);
    cout << item.getReport();
    placeCursor(screen, 13, 25);
    cout << "********************************" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Constructors _construct_. Use a method to display stuff

Comment: You declaration to Heading class on the main, might be causing this. If you declare a variable of type Heading without specifying which constructor the variable you just declared should call, then the compiler will call the default constructor, which in this case happen to be assigning company = "ABC Industries" and report = "Report".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Here's a version that shows how to have the defaults show up when you expect them:

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bb14873b94f88fd)**

```
class Heading {
private:
    string company;
    string report;

    static string defaultCompany() { return "ABC Industries"; }
    static string defaultReport () { return "Report"; }

public:
    Heading(string const& c = defaultCompany(), string const& r = defaultReport()) 
        : company(c), report(r) { }

    void storeInfo(string const& c, string const& r)
    {
        company = c;
        report  = r;
    }

    string getCompany() const { return company.empty()? defaultCompany() : company; }
    string getReport()  const { return report.empty()?  defaultReport()  : report;  }
};
```

As you can see, you need to check whether the input received was empty, because you'll always unconditionally set the members in `storeInfo`.

Full program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace // windows_cruft
{
    using HANDLE = unsigned;
    HANDLE STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = 1;
    HANDLE GetStdHandle(HANDLE) {return 42;}

    struct COORD { int X,Y; };
    void SetConsoleCursorPosition(HANDLE, COORD){}
}

class Heading {
private:
    string company;
    string report;

    static string defaultCompany() { return "ABC Industries"; }
    static string defaultReport () { return "Report"; }

public:
    Heading(string const& c = defaultCompany(), string const& r = defaultReport()) 
        : company(c), report(r) { }

    void storeInfo(string const& c, string const& r)
    {
        company = c;
        report  = r;
    }

    string getCompany() const { return company.empty()? defaultCompany() : company; }
    string getReport()  const { return report.empty()?  defaultReport()  : report;  }
};

void storeInfo(Heading&);
void showInfo(HANDLE, Heading);
void placeCursor(HANDLE, Heading);

int main() {
    Heading company;
    HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    storeInfo(company);
    showInfo(screen, company);
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

/*****storeInfo*****/
void storeInfo(Heading &item) {
    string company;
    string report;
    cout << "\nPlease enter the company name.\n";
    getline(cin, company);
    cout << "\nPlease enter the report name.\n";
    getline(cin, report);
    item.storeInfo(company, report);
}

/*****placeCursor*****/
void placeCursor(HANDLE screen, int row, int col) {
    COORD position;
    position.Y = row;
    position.X = col;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);
}

/*****showInfo*****/
void showInfo(HANDLE screen, Heading item) {
    //system("cls");
    placeCursor(screen, 6, 25);
    cout << "********************************" << endl;
    placeCursor(screen, 8, 32);
    cout << item.getCompany() << endl;
    placeCursor(screen, 11, 36);
    cout << item.getReport() << endl;
    placeCursor(screen, 13, 25);
    cout << "********************************" << endl;
}
```

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I've implemented the rest and fixed some elements for style: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bb14873b94f88fd

Answer (score 2):

You have your assignments back to front. This:

```
void Heading::storeInfo(string c, string r) {
    c = company;
    r = report;
}
```

should be this:

```
void Heading::storeInfo(string c, string r) {
    company = c;
    report = r;
}
```

As sehe mentions, defining it:

```
void Heading::storeInfo(const string& c, const string& r)
```

allows the compiler to help you avoid things like this.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the implementation. That's even funnier than the bug I suspected. Another reason to either pass by `const&` by default (except, in this case the parameters might be `&&` insteadm but I digress)

Comment: Tried what you suggested - and it does allow for information entered to be displayed, however, now if nothing is entered it doesn't display the default information of the "ABC Industries" and "Report"

Comment: @user2792977: It's not clear what you mean by "if nothing is entered." If you mean that if empty lines are entered in the standalone `storeInfo()` function, then that'll be because you update the object whether anything is entered or not, i.e. you assign empty strings to the class members. If this isn't what you mean, you'll need to post additional code showing what you do mean.

Comment: For example when the program prompts the user to enter the company name and report they just hit enter instead. Sorry, I have a hard time putting into words my problem, as I'm only 2 months into my very first programming class. ;)

Comment: Then like I said, you call `item.storeInfo(company, report);` whether they enter anything or not, so you're overwriting whatever you put as your default values in your constructor.

Comment: @user2792977 See my answer, for a cleaner approach to get the default values as you intend